# Is it professional to include the "Sent from my device" in an email signature?

Tags: professionalism, email

My iPhone signature is automatically "Sent from my iPhone". My iPad does the same, and on my Android tablet, I get "Sent using [Cloud Magic Email](http://cloudmagic.com)". Finally, on Desktop, it says "Sent Sent from [Nylas N1](https://nylas.com/n1?ref=n1)"

While I like all these apps / devices, and I'm happy to support them via a single line advertisement, I am not sure how professional it appears.

I sometimes remove the signature but I'm never sure if I need to or not, and I normally leave it after a couple of email exchanges.

Is there a sliding scale - is this fine for internal emails, but not advised externally, or should I just disable the signature for my work account?

Comment: People are more accepting of spelling mistakes when they know you typed your reply on a phone rather than sitting at your workstation. As far as I'm concerned that's the only reason to leave it in.

Comment: Personally, when I see those lines my first thought is that the sender isn't tech savvy enough to remove it and replace with their own signature.

Comment: You don't need to leave these messages there to "support" the products. You supported them already by buying the devices. Now customize it to show your own signature.

Comment: @Brandin The apps are all free, so I've paid nothing. I like Nylas (it's open source) and Cloud Magic (it's amazing). The devices I have paid for, yes.

Comment: @Tim The correct thing is to customize the message and only mention the app or device in your signature if that's actually something you would have done anyway. Regardless of how much or how little you've paid, the e-mail is 100% yours. Nylas et al own no part of it and you have no obligation to "advertise" for them.

Comment: @Brandin Sure, that's not my question. I'm happy for the signature to be there (I customised it already) - my question is "is this unprofessional" (and opinions seem mixed).

Comment: @Tim So you mean you specifically customised it to say "Sent from my iPhone"? The problem is, that sounds like it's the default message. So when I see that I'll probably just think you're a little clueless about technology. But if you actually wanted it to say that...

Comment: @Brandin It was customised to say "Sent from Nylas N1". I remove the rest of the sentence "the open, extensible email client"

Comment: My compromise was to change the signature to "Sent from a tablet; apologies for typing or autocorrect errors." They don't need to know the specific device, and if the mfgr wants me to advertise for them they can offer to pay me.

Comment: I've never known anyone that has been bothered by it. When I read an email, I care about the contents of the email, not the fluff around it. It's part of the reason why I've never set a signature.

Comment: @keshlam: "They don't need to know the specific device, and if the mfgr wants me to advertise for them they can offer to pay me." - that comment seems oddly beside the point, given that the OP has expressed their willingness to provide that advertising and to inform others about the specific device/software.

Comment: I wouldn't consider them unprofessional, I do consider them annoying.  They add nothing, get rid of it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't see this as unprofessional at all.  We live on our mobile devices and people should expect that they could get messages sourced from there.  More importantly, it helps set context for the message.  If I shoot back a short quick reply from my phone, the recipients can see that I may not be in a good place to give a detailed reply.

Comment: You can increase the chances of that by editing the message to say "sent from my [whatever] - please excuse typos or short replies" or "send from my [whatever] - if you need more details when I am at my desk please reply asking for them" and so on. I generally replace iPhone, BlackBerry, SuperAmazingWhizzoPhone with just "phone" or "tablet" as appropriate to remove any sense of advertising for the vendor or showing off how cool you are to own a [whatever]

Comment: @KateGregory So would you suggest the "Nylas N1" which my desktop sends is unadvisable?

Comment: I would, yes. I don't think what provider or server or vendor you use is really relevant. The fact that you're using an onscreen keyboard or answering from the changeroom at the gym may be.

Comment: I disagree.  The point of sending mail from mobile devices is that the recipients should neither know nor care where you sent it from.

Comment: I think the point of sending mail from a mobile device is the question of greater accessibility.  Whether or not someone knows or cares that it's mobile is context sensitive.

Comment: Even better would be to be professional and not have typos in a business email, regardless of the device you write it on.

Answer (score 11):

While I personally don't care for it, that has become so ubiquitous in recent years that it's completely unavoidable.

At this stage of the game, I think it is so prevalent that the question of whether or not it's professional no longer matters.

It just is.

Edit: there is a potential case where you may not want to have it. If you have a client or someone else that is assuming that you're actually working in the office as opposed to working from home or somewhere else, that may leave the impression that you're out and about. If the person to whom you're sending an email already thinks that you aren't in the office much, that may perpetuate that perception.

Comment: @dan1111 Presumable Cristopher means that it's become so prevalent that you can't avoid people who keep this signature active. As an extension of that, there won't be anyone left who hasn't seen this before or who thinks less of someone for doing it, which means that it can't be considered unprofessional these days.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is 'yes', it is professional. In fact, it's not just professional but desirable. And I base that answer not on opinion but on reviewing the research on the topic.

Let me explain.

I read this post a few weeks ago, and was intrigued not just by the number of answers but by the lack of consensus. Like others here, I'd assumed this question was now redundant, given how we've all long gotten over the whole 'look at me with a new iPhone' thing. But I'd begun wondering about it again after the default signature reappeared on my iPhone after a software update.

I'd hesitated to just change it. (OK, I procrastinated, as I was irritated that I had to do it again, having carefully set up my mobile signature a couple of years back.) Then I wondered if I was actually better off leaving it as it was. Which is why this thread caught my eye.

Rather than just add my two cents', I decided to see if there had been any research on the topic. It turns out that there has.

A few years ago, two social scientists at the University of Oklahoma tested emails with and without 'Sent from my iPhone' on over a hundred volunteers, to see how each affected perception of the sender. In particular, they wanted to test whether the line reduced the damaging effect of grammar errors and typos.

What they found was that, while such mistakes did indeed have a negative effect on perception, 'Sent from my iPhone' significantly reduced that effect.

The reason is that we're all programmed to look for cues that help us judge the people we're communicating with. In a nutshell, we want to know whether we can trust and believe them – a concept covered by an idea called [Uncertainty Reduction Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_reduction_theory) (first put forward in 1975). Mistakes in an email increase uncertainty about the sender, but other cues called '[high-warrant' cues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warranting_theory) can reduce it. 'Sent from my iPhone' is the second type of cue.

So those people here who've suggested it buys you leeway are spot-on: it repairs *some* of the damage that typos (or hurried, terse replies) do to your credibility.

The original [Oklahoma study research paper is here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00909882.2012.712707).
I've also written up the research findings in more detail on my blog [here](http://robashton.wpengine.com/why-you-should-still-include-sent-from-my-iphone-in-your-mobile-email-signature/).

I may have geeked out a little, but it strikes me as a fascinating area – not least because I've never come across these ideas in any business books (despite working in communication for about 25 years). If the people we email (etc.) are all driven by the desire to reduce uncertainty, then tweaking what we write to help them with that (by including these cues) can only improve our work relationships.

Adding something like 'Sent from my mobile – apologies for any typos or strange predictive text' seems like one easy, simple way to do just that.

Comment: Sounds like you should just add that to every short email you send, then ;)

Comment: @Erik Personally, I rarely email from a device other than my phone now -
 I have a significant journey time each day. But perhaps I will add it as my default signature.

Comment: Last comment sent from Joe Strazzere's phone. That's probably why his thought was interrupted mid-sentence.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere If you've never sent an email with a typo in it, you're better than I am. The brain sees what it expects to see, not what's there. The only foolproof ways to catch every error are to print out the email and check each word individually or give it to someone else to proof. (I base that on training 40,000 people in business writing; I agree this stuff matters.) Neither method is practical in this case. Stating that you wrote an email on a mobile is a proven way to mitigate mistakes that slip through and so build trust. And building relationships based on trust is professional.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm not trying to argue that mistakes are ok. They're not. (They irritate me too – but that might be my age.) Rather, I'm just reporting on the research. The authors of the Oklahoma study found no statistical differences between different age demographics.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I definitely agree that you should modify it, for lots of reasons (eg including a phone number, promoting your business and not Apple's, or just showing that you know how). I guess the take-home from this study is just that you should also indicate that you composed it on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

Everything we do is in a context.  Some of us have to deal with phone calls both in the office as well as on the road.  Any client would be real stupid to not consider the FACT that certain things just can't be achieved in a conversation when either a service provider OR the client happens to be on a mobile phone in some place where the background noise can't be controlled.

As such, the same works for messages.  The footer works, because it says that the sender is not *immediately* available for certain types of exchanges via e-mail.  It actually helps to set realistic expectations, which is MORE professional, in my opinion.  It doesn't lower the level of service; in fact, it improves it.

The only thing I'd change is for the message to read "sent from my mobile", vs advertising someone's brand name.

Answer (score -1):

> I am not sure how professional it appears.

To me it appears like you are using a private device. Companies don't do that. They *may* allow the use of a private device but they surely don't allow private devices to alter your messages sent in their name.

Sending me information that is not part of a professional message is unprofessional. If you aren't an Apple representative and we aren't talking about iPhones, information like "sent from my iPhone" is an advertisement for a third party. I don't want that from a business partner.

If you are mentioning it to apologize for poor message quality, that appears  unprofessional as well. Don't send me automated excuses in advance, instead improve your message quality. *That* would be professional.

Obviously I don't expect a professional mail from a private device if it *is* a private device. Someone who calls in sick from his private phone in the morning can have any signature he likes.

To summarize: sending me unsolicited advertisements in the mail does not appear professional to me.

Comment: "To me it appears like you are using a private device. Companies don't do that."  Not true.  Lots of companies allow you to use private devices for work, even major companies.  "[Bring Your Own Device] is making significant inroads in the business world, with about 75% of employees in high growth markets such as Brazil and Russia and 44% in developed markets already using their own technology at work."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_your_own_device

Comment: I agree that these signatures are unprofessional though.

Comment: "It appears like you are using a private device". This is true and it does have an impact on "professionalism" but it may be like a double-edged sword. For example, if you have to deal with clients, it's maybe convenient for them to have the impression that you're responding in your off hours and can be reached all hours of the day. But once they have that expectation, you essentially can never put your work away.

Comment: Maybe it's just where I live (NYC metro) and work (finance/tech) but a high percentage of people I know use their private device to interact with their work mail and other services.  The distinction of private device really doesn't seem to come into play.

Comment: -1. I'm not sure what this answer is trying to say... You've taken it from a default, single sentence signature to 6 lines of unprofessional content. I'm not asking if I should credit Alice the intern, I'm asking if "Sent from my / via my [item]" looks unprofessional. "I don't care what brand of jeans you wear or what shampoo you use, either" hence I'm not telling you. And the question is not "do people care?" (I'm sure some do and some don't. The question "Sent from my / via my [item]" looks unprofessional, which this doesn't answer...

Comment: @Tim you may want to read my last sentence

Comment: @nvoigt I read it. I don't think that you can describe "sent from my iPhone" as an unsolicited advertisement - it's not like it's at the top of the message, preventing access to the message. I understand your argument, but the content leading up to the final sentence sounds like you are concluding "Setup by Alice the intern who does a really great job!" etc is the issue you are... arguing against.

Comment: @cdkMoose Maybe a high percentage of people in your area work too much. Doesn't make it right. It may be better for everyone to leave work at work.

Comment: @brandin, I was responding to " using a private device.  Companies don't do that."  Companies do do that, I agree we should do it less, but that is the current reality, which helps determine if it might currently be considered professional or not.

Comment: @Tim I have updated my post to better reflect my opinion on this.

Comment: @cdkMoose Professionalism in this context is not just one-dimensional. Say you send business updates to your boss while on the commute. So maybe that's "professional" because you're so attentive, even while on the commute. Problem is, now you're basically setting an expectation that you may not want to live up to later. Maybe you decide you just want to relax and turn off the phone while on the commute. Etc.

Comment: Can anybody please explain the downvotes? If you think this is opinion and you don't like it, feel free to close-vote the question as opinion-based. If you think the answer is factually wrong, please inform me.

Comment: Please note that I take no stance on whether you should use a private phone or not. I don't care as long as you send professional messages with it. Sending unsolicited third party advertisements is unprofessional, regardless of device or company policy regarding devices.